# Communication via postMessage()

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm working on a Firefox extension, and I need to be able to communicate between the addon script and the content scripts. I have one direction of this working: passing the URL of a script from the addon script to a content script. However, I need to be able to go in the reverse direction, as well. My main.js file looks like this:

```
var data = require("self").data;
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "https://trello.com/board/*",
  contentScriptWhen: 'end',
  contentScriptFile: data.url("scrumello_beta.user.js"),
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.postMessage(data.url("scrumello_beta.js"));
    worker.on("message", function(addonMessage)
    {
        console.log(addonMessage);
    });
  }
});
```

In the client script, I have the following method:

```
    function OpenProcess(SCRNumber)
    {
        self.postMessage(SCRNumber); 
    }
```

However, when this method is called, I get the following error:

```
Timestamp: 8/7/2012 12:15:58 PM
Error: NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments [nsIDOMWindow.postMessage]
Source File: resource://jid0-3mulsijczmtjeuwkd5npayasqf8-at-jetpack/scogan-3/data/scrumello_beta.js
Line: 1038
```

This prevents the worker.on("message"... event from ever being triggered. As far as I know, postMessage only takes one argument, so any help here would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I've changed the postMessage call to

```
self.postMessage(SCRNumber, "*");
```

I wrapped it in console.log's, both of which are being printed, so I have to assume the message is actually being posted. However, the event handler in main.js never picks up the message, because the console.log I have in there is never printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it. (Notice that I never used `self.postmessage`)

Addon script (main.js) to content script communication:

```js
contentPage = pageMod.PageMod({
  onAttach: function(worker) {

    // Post a message directly to the content script
    worker.postMessage("any thing you want to respond");

    // Depending on the message, respond with different data
    worker.port.on('getFact', function() {
      worker.postMessage("any thing you want to respond");
    });
    worker.port.on('getEnabled', function() {
      worker.postMessage("any thing you want to respond");
    });
  }
});
```

--

Here's the content script responding to the add-on script:

```js
// Get data from the addon script
self.on('message', function(msg) {
  // Do something depending on the message passed
});
```

--

Last, the content script can communicate to the add-on script like this:

```js
self.port.emit("message to send to add-on script")
```

The above code will trigger the `worker.port.on` code in the main.js.

Comment: So, what goes in the worker.port.on as the first argument? I tried putting in "message", but the event is never triggered. I know that the self.port.emit is being called because I have a console.log there to show it's there, but the trigger I put in the worker.port.on is never called.

Comment: first argument of worker.port.on is the first argument of self.port.emit in the content script. 

Each worker.port.on can only handle one type of emit msg. So in my example those two worker.port.on handles `self.port.emit("getFact")` and `self.port.emit("getEnabled")`

Comment: I actually figured that out in between when I asked and when you answered. However, I have another issue. It seems that self.port is undefined when I try to call it. Is there any reason this might be?

Comment: `self.port` only exists in the content script created by pageMod. So the only reason I can think of is that its not being called in the content script you specified. `contentScriptFile: data.url("scrumello_beta.user.js")`

Comment: Ah, I see. Alright, I defined both files that I'm using in my add-on as content scripts, like this:

contentScriptFile: [data.url("scrumello_beta.user.js"), data.url("scrumello_beta.js")],

I'm still getting the error that self.port doesn't exist. Am I able to do it this way?

Comment: Never mind, I solved the problem. I didn't realize that the Addon console was separate from the Firebug console, so I thought that my logs weren't being printed. They were, in fact, just being printed to the wrong one. Which means that you're correct and this is working as we both thought it should be. Thanks so much for your help, and sorry to trouble you like this.

Comment: No problem Sean! Glad it helped.

Comment: Hmm, actually, it's still saying self.port is undefined, even though I have the script marked as a content script. Any idea why self.port would exist in one content script but not another?

Comment: Maybe how you loaded the content script?
I'm loading it like this:
`contentScriptFile: [data.url("one.js"), data.url("two.js")]`

Comment: Yeah, that's how I saw to do it. One possibility that I was thinking of is that the second script is being injected into Trello at runtime. But the script itself is being made into a content script before this happens, so I don't know if that's having an effect on it or now. If it is, I'm gonna have to find a different way to do this.

Comment: self.port should always exist in a content script. Hard to say what your problem is without seeing all the code, but here is a very simple example that uses self.port: https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1068480/latest/